# How can I call an attrib same as value on javascript?

Tags: javascript

Option:

```
<select class="form-control se" style="width: 155px;" onchange="showOptions(this)" id="tripSelect">
    <option class="dd" id="opt{{$z}}" value="{{$blah}}" data-egid="{{$optionID}}">{{$event->trip_name}}</option>
</select>
```

I'm using this console:

```
function showOptions(s) {
  console.log(s[s.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-egid"));
}
```

and it's working but when I used the same

```
var trip_id = $('#tripSelect :selected').getAttribute("data-egid"));
//---------------------
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "{{blah blah}}",
        data: {
            event_group_id: trip_id,
        },
       //...
    });
```

It's now telling me that getAttribute is not a function

Comment: Not enough information to help you.  What is `s`?

Comment: @Brad please don mind the console cos it's working just fine. The problem is in the 2nd `$.ajax` it's telling me that getAttribute is not a function

Comment: Please don't mind, 'eh?  You realize that this discrepancy is the whole cause of the problem?

Comment: @Brad sorry didn't know that. I updated the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getAttribute()` is a function on a regular DOMElement, not some jQuery-wrapped object.

You didn't show us the relevant code, but somewhere in your top sample, if that's working, `s[s.selectedIndex]` is a regular DOMElement.

In your lower code, `$('#tripSelect :selected')` returns a jQuery-wrapped array of elements, which have different functions.

If you wanted that first element, you could have probably done something like:

```
$('#tripSelect :selected')[0].getAttribute("data-egid");
```